# How to create bucket of counters in cassandra with composite columns

Tags: cassandra

How can I create a list of counters as a composite column in Cassandra. The problem I am trying to solve is storing count of visits to a particular object. The model in json representation is something like this:

ColumnFamily: view_counts
RowKey: object_id

value: 
{
    total: 10,
    referrer: {
       facebook: 2,
       twitter: 5,
       direct: 2,
       other: 1
    }
    country: {
       australia: 4,
       us:  4,
       other: 2
    }
}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What you want is something like this (where X:Y is a composite column):

```
ColumnFamily: view_counts
Rows:
object_id -> { "total": 10,
               "referrer:facebook": 2,
               "referrer:twitter": 5,
               "referrer:direct": 2, 
               "referrer:other": 1,
               "country:australia": 4,
               "country:us": 4, 
               "country:other": 2 }
```

Then when you get a new visit to Object6 via Twitter from Australia, you do the following increments:

```
incr view_counts[Object6]['total']
incr view_counts[Object6]['referrer:twitter']
incr view_counts[Object6]['country:australia']
```

There are different ways you could arrange this, of course - you could also put the composites in the row keys:

```
total:object_id    -> { "count": 10 }
referrer:object_id -> { "facebook": 2,
                        "twitter": 5,
                        "direct": 2, 
                        "other": 1 }
country:object_id  -> { "australia": 4, 
                        "us": 4, 
                        "other": 2 }
```

or dispense with composite columns altogether and use separate column families for `view_counts_by_referrer` and `view_counts_by_country`.

Realtime analytics systems like [Acunu Analytics](http://www.acunu.com/blogs/andy-twigg/acunu-analytics-preview/) will do all this for you, so you can just specify a query like `SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(user_ip_address) FROM view_counts WHERE object = Object6 AND time > '7 days ago' GROUP BY referrer` and it will work out all the appropriate counters behind the scenes.

(p.s. Supercolumns are deprecated, since you can't modify only part of a supercolumn, which slows things down.)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate,
I cannot find the hector API for counter API on composite column. There is only API for creating counters and super columns.
Can you please post a very small sample with hector client ?

Cheers

Answer (score -3):

Why not just use a supercolumnfamily, with a super column for referrers and countries?